# Funeral procession of the daughter of Allah's Apostle - hadith explanation

Tags: hadith-interpretation, sahih-bukhari

> Narrated Anas: We were in the funeral procession of the daughter of
>   Allah's Apostle and Allah's Apostle was sitting near the grave and I
>   saw his eyes full of tears. He said, "Is there anyone amongst you who
>   did not have **sexual relations with his wife last night?**" Abu Talha
>   replied in the affirmative. And so Allah's Apostle told him to get
>   down in her grave and he got down in her grave and buried her.

**Sahih Buckari BooK of funerals number 426**

Why is an action of previous night matter while burying someone?

Answer (score 1):

According to Fathul Baari and Umdatul Qari (commentary on Bukhari), it could have different meaning:

- who did not made any sin last night (supporteي by Tahawih where it is said " يُقَاوِلْ  " instead of " يقارف " which mean who has not stay until late to speak (some kind of speech after isha are regarded as makrouh)
- who did not have sexual relations with his wife last night

If it's the second option, then what was the hikmat ? According to Umdatul Qari

- The one who did have sexual relations with his wife last night may be a little "carefree"  when taking care of the body, thinking that his desire is down now...
- Hadhrat Uthman RAD (the husband of the daughter of Allah's Apostle) was having sexual relations with his slave the night before. The prophet SAW didn't appreciate that he was doing that while the wealth of the wife/daughter was declining so much. He used this "kinayah" to prevent him from getting down in her grave

Comment: Does Umdatul Qari book give a source about  Hadhrat Uthman you mention here?. If not then it is a slander against Hadhrat Uthman.

Comment: It is not a slander because it is allowed to have relations with slaves (under some conditions).